# What software is there available for quantitative structure–activity relationship (QSAR) pharmacological studies?

Tags: biochemistry, bioinformatics, pharmacology, theoretical-biology, medicinal-chemistry

QSAR modelling in pharmacology basically hangs on using mathematical modelling to approximate the effects different molecules will have on various pharmacological targets. I would like to know what software is available to assist me in doing these studies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the G6G Directory of OMICS and Intelligent software, I searched for "QSAR Analysis, and received two product abstracts:

1) SYBYL®-X Suite which contained:

- 3D QSAR: use the power of industry leading CoMFA in a new way to
  generate novel ideas for R-groups - predict the level of biological
  activity or potency based on structure-activity data, Not just yes/No
  activity predictions;
- Cheminformatics: produce highly focused queries that avoid false
  positives using a rich set of 3D queries; on-the-fly conformational
  searching means you only store a single conformation of your
  molecules, keeping database size small and very transportable; and...

  Link to this abstract:
  http://g6g-softwaredirectory.com/bio/proteomics/structure-modeling/20710-Tripos-SYBYL-X-Suite.php

2) Fujitsu GhostMiner

GhostMiner can be employed in a number of business intelligence areas and the following areas:

- Bioinformatics - genetics, proteomics, Quantitative Structure
  Activity Relationship (QSAR) modeling...

  Link to this abstract:
  http://g6g-softwaredirectory.com/ai/neural-networks/20154-FQS-Poland-Fujitsu-GhostMiner.php

Perhaps the above will help.

Answer (score 0):

Click2drug is a good ressource for in silico studies.

[See this link.](http://www.click2drug.org/index.html#QSAR)